# How to use async await with out parameter in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

How can we use async-await in C# with out parameter safely.

for example

```
async public void someMethod(){
     await someOtherMethod (out string outputFromSomeOtherMethod);
     .......
     .....

}
```

Comment: use async void only for event handlers. return a task

Comment: In your sample, where method used with `await`, using of `out` parameter is safe enough. Since next line where this parameter can be consumed will be executed only after method completes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, you don't (and you can't), we use a `return`

*Also, when you think about it, it doesn't make any sense, its a task that finishes when it likes, if you could do that you would be forcing it to wait for the out parameter*

```
public async Task<SomeResult> someOtherMethod() { .. }

...

var myAwesomeResult = await someOtherMethod();
```

Also, you cold use a `delegate`, `func<T,U>` or `Action<T>` as a parameter

```
public async Task someOtherMethod(Action<bool> someResult)
{
   await somestuff;
   someResult(true);
}

...

await someOtherMethod(b => YayDoSomethingElse(b));
```

Ooor as [Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white) commented, you could return a `ValueTuple` if you need easy access to multiple return types

```
public async Task<(int someValue,string someOtherValue)> someOtherMethod() {.. }
```

Comment: you could also return a tuple that might make sense.

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks updated and attributed